# How to Connect a Wii U Gamepad to a Wii U WITHOUT the TV?

Tags: technical-issues, wii-u

I bought a used Wii U console that didn't come with a Wii U gamepad and bought a gamepad separately.

I can't see the TV connection, as the Wii U is clearly not in AV Video output, and the HDMI inputs on my TV have long since died on me. I would like to connect my Wii U gamepad to the system, but you apparently also need the TV to sync a Wii U gamepad to a Wii U.

Anything I can do to sync the gamepad to the console without a TV?

Answer (score 3):

You need a TV or other form of display to finish the process of setting up a Wii U out of the box. (or if it's factory reset)

This can be connected via the analog video output, or HDMI on the Wii U.

The connected display is *only needed for the **initial setup***, and after it is finished, the console can be used with the gamepad alone, or with the TV as you see fit.

In your case; I'd suggest finding any TV with an analog video input, and connect the Wii U to that for the setup.
The Wii U uses the same shaped analog AV adapter as the Wii, so if you have one of those lying around, you can use that.

Answer (score -3):

Turn the Wii U Gamepad and the Wii U Console on.

Press the SYNC buttons on the Wii U Console **twice** and the Wii U GamePad once to pair them. (Front at the Wii U Console, back of the Wii U GamePad)

Then enter the symbols shown on the TV screen in order, starting from the left, on the Wii U GamePad.

Comment: If the TV doesn't function, the OP can't complete this process.

Comment: Then he can't sync the device. Or OP uses a monitor or other kind of display.